# Time Dialation, what is the maximum time which has been travelled?

Tags: time, relativity

Due to the relativity of time, if something travels faster its time goes slowly.
Until now what is the maximum time a person has travelled into the future (or the maximum change in two clocks)?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about humans? Or about any object we have accelerated to a high speed? If the latter the record is held by either the particles in the LHC or LEP2.

Comment: I would want to know about humans

Answer (score 1):

So first, this is a misstatement. The difference in time is relative. Meaning neither reference frame experiences a difference in the rate of the passage of time. It's only when clocks are compared is there a difference. Also being in a gravity well will ADD to dilation not cancel it out.

Answer (score 0):

On the International Space Station, the gravitational [time dilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) nearly cancels the [time dilation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation) due to velocity. After spending six months on the station, astronauts have aged only about 0.005 seconds less than the people on Earth.

"Without accounting for the effects of rotation, proximity to the Earth's gravitational well will cause a clock on the planet's surface to accumulate around 0.0219 fewer seconds over a period of one year than would a distant observer's clock." Thus a person who lived 100 years on the Earth would be about 2 seconds "into the future"compared to a distant observer, more that any astronaut so far.

$\,$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fastest speed of humans [relative to Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vehicle_speed_records#Relative_to_Earth) was apparently the crew of Apollo 10 during the re-entry phase at an impressive 39,897 km/hr.

While this sounds impressive, the speed of light is a far more impressive 1,080,000,000 km/hr.  Yes, that's a *billion* km/hr.

The time dilation effect of this was a factor of 0.999999999318.

Apollo 10 spent 8 days in space, but let's be generous and use the time traveling at that speed as the same as the longest time in space by one person which is an impressive 437.7 days by Russian [Valeri Polyakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeri_Polyakov) (who cranked up an additional 240 days as well).

If we use this time and speed we get a total time dilation effect of about 0.026 seconds !

But of course the total effect Valeri Polyakov experienced was smaller as he traveled in orbit in the [Mir space station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir).  That was slower compared to the Apollo 10 crew's peak velocity and he experienced about half effect that at around the 0.0125 seconds mark.

Comment: You answer does not indicate that you have accounted for the opposite effect of the gravitational time dilation that nearly cancels out the velocity time dilation.

Comment: ISS and Mir orbit in low Earth orbit and I think that the net effect is close to what I've described for these orbits.  I think the graph in your own answer would agree with this.

Comment: ok so it seems that a very little time has been travelled .what is the possibility of something(human or machine) being able to travel a day or year into the future.

Comment: and also it is impossible to travel back with time dialation ,am I true